# Is it polite to ask about scholarship/assistantship opportunities during a Ph.D. interview at a UK university?

Tags: phd, funding, interview, teaching-assistant, research-assistantship

I am scheduled for an interview in August for a Ph.D. program that I applied to at a UK university. However, even if I get an offer of place on the program, I would not be able to accept it unless I also receive funding. So, is it okay to ask the panelists after or during the interview about the scholarship/assistantship opportunities that the university offers? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to have any more information than is already on the university website.

Comment: Yes, it's both a polite and sensible thing to ask.

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a bit variety in how funding for UK PhDs works, but I am not aware of any situation where you would apply for a scholarship via the university AFTER an admissions interview. Instead, I'd expect one of the following setups:

A. For a university with a lot of attached funding (eg Cambridge), you indicate that you want to be considered for scholarships on your initial application. Funding and admission are then mostly aligned, although it is still possible to get admitted but not funded. At the moment you could be interviewed, the funding deadlines are long over.

B. A university with limited scholarship funding will usually advertise scholarships or RA positions directly, and the admissions process is integrated in that. Most scholarships will be restricted to UK residents. If you apply directly for the PhD programme, you are exected to have external/your own funding.

So unless the university you've applied to follows a different model, you may have wasted everyones (including your own) time already.